# Deleting Items from Ms-Access C# with Repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have a repeater that fetches information from the database and displays it; also I have a button beside it and when I click on the button, that `id` should be deleted from the database (MS Access).

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
     OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
     OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id")%>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="deletethis"/>
        <br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|mydb.mdb";//location of db

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users", conn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "deletethis")
    {
        // the program doesn't get here
        string id = string.Empty;

        Label lblid = new Label();
        lblid = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("id");
        id = lblid .Text;

        Label2.Text = "Button is clicked on id "+ id;
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

So what happens is when I click on the button, it doesn't ever reach this line:

```
(e.CommandName == "deletethis")
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun, try `if (e.CommandName.ToLower().Equals("deletethis"))`.

i was just reading this sample - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx - and realized that a CommandName isn't even required for rep_ItemCommand to run. try running some code that doesn't check for the CommandName and see if it works. if it doesn't, it makes me wonder what's happening in `OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound"`.